# Regular expression allowing alphabets and forward slash only

Tags: c#, regex, validation

my requirement is that i need to get input from user regarding a folder path the validation which I require for it is i need users to input only alphabets and forward slash(no other special characters and also no space), also the forward slash is optional.

For Example :

FlceIn           - Valid Path

FlceIn/          - Valid Path

FlceIn\          - In Valid Path

FlceIn/Name/     - Valid Path

Currently after goggling the i am using the expression [a-zA-Z//] but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^([A-Za-z/]*)$` will match what you are describing. Regular expressions require a lot of learning and practice, a lot of study on the subject is definitely recommended.

Comment: "a lot of study on the subject is definitely recommended" --- it won't ever happen as soon as there are hundreds of people giving free fish on SO

Comment: @zerkms gotta love the internet I have so much free space in my brain for other useful stuff